# Open maps.google.com from standalone application with some markers

Tags: google-maps, maps

I have a standalone application which calculates some geo locations.  I'd like the application to open a browser, navigate to `maps.google.com` (or another map provider?), and display markers at the geo locations.

You can do this, for instance, if you want to display a route in google maps.  Just have my application open a browser window and point it to:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr={start address}&daddr={destination address}
```

However, I have more than 2 locations and I don't want directions, just markers.  Any idea how to do it?

Note that I don't want my application to display the map, I want it to display in a standard browser.  So I don't think the API can help here.  Or can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at some [map parameters](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters) and also since you did not specified if you want static or dynamic map there is always the [static maps api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  I don't want a static map, I want the result to be zoomable/pannable.